# SSRS lookup with source not in current tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have 3 tables that I want to show in a tablix SSRS report in 3.0.

```
Table 1 - policy ID, amt paid by company
```

Query - `Select * from table1 where amt paid by company <> 0`

```
Table 2 - policy ID, policy number, previous policy number
```

Query - `Select * from table2 where previous policy number <> ' '`

```
Table 3 - previous policy number, paid under prior company
```

Query - `Select * from table3 where paid under prior company <> 0`

I want to display the following columns on one tablix row per entry in table 1:

- Policy number
- amt paid by company
- previous policy number
- paid under prior company.

I created a tablix.  I can display everything from table 1 and use lookup for table 2 items but when I do a lookup for item from table 3 it gives me an error.

From my research about this error I understand it to mean I cannot use the source in lookup from any table but table 1 in my case. And I can only do one level in lookup.

I have looked and can find no example for this anywhere and I have tried other methods and cannot figure out how to get to that piece of data in table 3.

Is my only choice to combine tables 2 and 3 together then use in this report with the lookup?

Comment: Are you using text queries for generating the datasets? If so edit your question and include the query for every dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INNER JOIN  to get a dataset that contains all fields you require to show in the tablix.

```
SELECT
  table2.PolicyNumber,
  table1.AmntPaidByCompany,
  table2.PrevPolicyNumber,
  table3.PaidUnderPriorCompany
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table3
  ON table2.PrevPolicyNumber = table3.PrevPolicyNumber
INNER JOIN table1
  ON table1.PolicyID = table2.PolicyID
WHERE table1.AmntPaidByCompany <> 0
AND table2.PrevPolicyNumber <> ''
AND table3.PaidUnderPriorCompany <> 0
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/451528/joining-multiple-tables-similar-to-lookup-ssrs-function)</kbd>

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you Alejandro.  This worked.  I should have gotten that myself.   Sorry for the delay in reply.  Got distracted on other things.

Comment: You are welcome, if my answer solved your use you can select it as correct answer or up-vote it. [How does accept an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)